# How do you declare abstract object values and methods in scala?

Tags: scala

I want to specify an animals color once, and it is the same for all animals of the same species.

So I'd like to do:

```
abstract object Animal {val color: String}
```

And then specify individual animals colors with

```
object Dog extends Animal {val color = "green"}
```

This needs to be in the object, as I already have a convention which cannot be changed of only making animals with the factory method also declared in the Animal object, and the factory methods needs access to the color.
e.g.

```
abstract object Animal {
   val color: String
   def makeAnimal(args): Animal = ...
}
```

How do I actually do this in scala, given that "only classes can have declared but undefined members"?

I can think of a hacky way to do this using traits, but I'm hoping there is something better.

[EDIT]
So it turns out I can't use traits to hold the values/methods for complicated reasons.
The current solution involves staticly registering the child object with the parent object using a trait, and that allows me to access the non-trait values and methods which must be defined in an object. I'm still hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 16):

You can't extend `object`s, by definition. So yes, you need a trait, but I don't see anything hacky about this:

```
trait AnimalCompanion {
  val color: String
  def makeAnimal(args): Animal // if you have same args everywhere
}

object Dog extends AnimalCompanion {
  val color = ...
  def makeAnimal(args) = ...
}
```

or even better

```
trait AnimalCompanion[A <: Animal] {
  val color: String
  def makeAnimal(args): A
}

class Dog extends Animal

object Dog extends AnimalCompanion[Dog] {
  val color = ...
  def makeAnimal(args): Dog = ...
}
```